# ListBox Filter, can't edit Textbox after using filter

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, filter

I wrote a Filter function included to a Textbox, it works and shows all the results i want to filter.

BUT, i want to manipulate the data after using the filter, but there is my problem. I cannot get access to the data i want to manipulate.

I think showing you the code is easier, because my problem is hard to explain - i think so.

UserForm with Textboxes and ListBox

[image]

Code for the Filter

```
Private Sub TextBox_Filter_Change()
Dim i As Long
Dim arrList As Variant

Me.ListBox_1.Clear
If Tabelle1.Range("A" & Tabelle1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row > 1 And Trim(Me.TextBox_Filter.Value) <> vbNullString Then
    arrList = Tabelle1.Range("A2:A" & Tabelle1.Range("A" & Tabelle1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value2
    For i = LBound(arrList) To UBound(arrList)
        If InStr(1, arrList(i, 1), Trim(Me.TextBox_Filter.Value), vbTextCompare) Then
            Me.ListBox_1.AddItem arrList(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
End If
If Me.ListBox_1.ListCount = 1 Then Me.ListBox_1.Selected(0) = True
```

Functions for saving and deleting my databoxes

```
Private Sub CommandButton_Speichern_Click()
Dim lZeile As Long
Dim Zeilennummer As Long

    If ListBox_1.ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub
    
    If Trim(CStr(TextBox_1.Text)) = "" Then
        
        MsgBox "Se müssen mindesens einen 1 eingeben!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "FEHLER!"
        
        Exit Sub
        
    End If
    
    lZeile = 2
    
    Do While Trim(CStr(Tabelle1.Cells(lZeile, 1).Value)) <> ""
        If ListBox_1.Column(0) = Trim(CStr(Tabelle1.Cells(lZeile, 1).Value)) And ListBox_1.Column(1) = Trim(CStr(Tabelle1.Cells(lZeile, 6).Value)) And ListBox_1.Column(2) = Trim(CStr(Tabelle1.Cells(lZeile, 7).Value)) Then
        
            
                Tabelle1.Cells(lZeile, 1).Value = Trim(CStr(TextBox_1.Text))
                Tabelle1.Cells(lZeile, 2).Value = TextBox_2.Text
                Tabelle1.Cells(lZeile, 3).Value = TextBox_3.Text
                Tabelle1.Cells(lZeile, 4).Value = TextBox_4.Text
                Tabelle1.Cells(lZeile, 5).Value = TextBox_5.Text
                Tabelle1.Cells(lZeile, 6).Value = TextBox_6.Text
                Tabelle1.Cells(lZeile, 7).Value = TextBox_7.Text
                Tabelle1.Cells(lZeile, 8).Value = TextBox_8.Text
                Tabelle1.Cells(lZeile, 9).Value = TextBox_9.Text
                Tabelle1.Cells(lZeile, 10).Value = TextBox_10.Text
                Tabelle1.Cells(lZeile, 11).Value = TextBox_11.Text
                Tabelle1.Cells(lZeile, 12).Value = TextBox_12.Text
                Tabelle1.Cells(lZeile, 13).Value = TextBox_13.Text
                Tabelle1.Cells(lZeile, 14).Value = TextBox_14.Text
                Tabelle1.Cells(lZeile, 15).Value = TextBox_15.Text
                
                Call UserForm_Initialize
                
            If ListBox_1.Text <> Trim(CStr(TextBox_1.Text)) Then
                Call UserForm_Initialize
                If ListBox_1.ListCount > 0 Then ListBox_1.ListIndex = 0
            End If

           Exit Do
        End If
        lZeile = lZeile + 1
        
    Loop

Call UserForm_Initialize

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton_Löschen_Click()
Dim Zeile As Long

    If ListBox_1.ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub
    
    lZeile = 2
    
    Do While Trim(CStr(Tabelle1.Cells(lZeile, 1).Value)) <> ""
    
        If ListBox_1.Column(0) = Trim(CStr(Tabelle1.Cells(lZeile, 1).Value)) And ListBox_1.Column(1) = Trim(CStr(Tabelle1.Cells(lZeile, 6).Value)) And ListBox_1.Column(2) = Trim(CStr(Tabelle1.Cells(lZeile, 7).Value)) Then
        
            Tabelle1.Rows(CStr(lZeile & ":" & lZeile)).Delete
            
            Call UserForm_Initialize
            If ListBox_1.ListCount > 0 Then ListBox_1.ListIndex = 0
            Exit Do
        End If
        
        lZeile = lZeile + 1
        
    Loop
```

and you need to see my user form initialization

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim lZeile As Long
Dim Zeilennummer As Long


TextBox_1 = ""
TextBox_2 = ""
TextBox_3 = ""
TextBox_4 = ""
TextBox_5 = ""
TextBox_6 = ""
TextBox_7 = ""
TextBox_8 = ""
TextBox_9 = ""
TextBox_10 = ""
TextBox_11 = ""
TextBox_12 = ""
TextBox_13 = ""
TextBox_14 = ""
TextBox_15 = ""



ListBox_1.Clear

lZeile = 2

Do While Trim(CStr(Tabelle1.Cells(lZeile, 1).Value)) <> ""

    With ListBox_1
    
    .AddItem Trim(CStr(Tabelle1.Cells(lZeile, 1).Value))
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = Trim(CStr(Tabelle1.Cells(lZeile, 6).Value))
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = Trim(CStr(Tabelle1.Cells(lZeile, 7).Value))
    
    lZeile = lZeile + 1
    

    End With
Loop


End Sub
```

Hopefully you can help me on this problem, i try to fix this for days

Comment: I don't think i understand your issue correctly. What do you mean by manipulating the data? Can you further explain what exactly causes a problem?

Comment: I get data from Excel and read it in via the input mask. 
I want to edit these rows in Excel using the mask.
This also works, but not if I filter the ListBox.